# how can install all packages without internet in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I am trying to install a software where there is no internet in system.So i need to install all packages which available in Ubuntu 16.04.How can do that?

Comment: All packages ? What you mean exactly

Comment: like when am trying to install libstc++6 i386 package it is asking dependency packages to be installed.So as i am not having internet in my machine how can install all dependency package and install it.

Comment: Get needed packages list with simulation `apt install -s <your package>` then download them from another machine and go to the offline one.

Comment: I got this one.Problem is those dependency package have other dependency pakages to be installed.So almost 300 packages which will be hectic to download and install.

Comment: any way to install all packages from iso file